# tengo una app nativa en Android studio. como puedo pasarla para sistema operativo IOS

Tags: android, android-studio

Lo que pasa es que tengo una aplicación móvil creada en Android studio y obviamente solo funcionara para sistemas operativos Android. alguien sabe como se puede pasar todo el código o de alguna forma crear una app para IOS utilizando la anterior.

Muchas gracias

Comment: No se puede,  Para crear para los 2 sistemas haciendo solo 1 trabajo esta react native agilisa eso, pero es un poquito mas lento a una app nativa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quisieras hacer una versión de tu app para iOS tendrías que volver a codificar todo el proyecto pero en swift, o usar alguna otra herramienta como flutter, xamarin que te genere la app tanto como en android y ios.
Pero intel creo un plugin (Multi-OS Engine) que se instala en Android Studio para poder desarrollar para iOS.